# Designing asynchronous procedure for downloading & displaying images

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I have a JSON feed which contains URLs for images. I am using `NSURLConnection` to download the JSON feed extract the URLs. I want to download all the images asynchronously. I subclassed `UIImage` and sent that class a URL which it downloads, one image at at a time, in an asynchronous manner.

First, is that a good way to do it? Second, I'd like to show four images at a time. Shouldn't I download every set of four together instead of downloading one by one?

My second concern is that I have two`NSURLConnection`s. That's probably bad. Should I use the very same `NSURLConnection` to download the JSON feed and at the same time get the image?

I am trying to display four images at a time, with a next button that displays the next four on the next line.

Comment: I wrote this today at work for downloading and updating adverts. Shame I don't have the code in front of me to give you any pointers.

Comment: Any hints/suggestions on design? I don't really need code - just design decision help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure UIImage is expected to be subclassed. If you need good design practice, you should have a look at [TopPaid](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TopPaid/Introduction/Intro.html)
sample code from Apple, as it is showing how to properly download a feed and then asynchronously download images. Take a close look at the `IconDownloader` class from this project, which is a class handling image downloading, and notifying its delegate when it's finished.

As far as I know there is no problem with having multiple NSURLConnections at a time. You might run into trouble if the number of connections becomes *very* large, because this could saturate the number of open file descriptors allowed on iPhone, or more likely create a memory warning. In your case if you only have 2 connections, you don't have any problem.